# There was a problem in setStyle Feature "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm having problems setting the color for the feature. It only added the color for the first time and then encountered the "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size overlapped" error. How do I fix it so that it doesn't happen?

I set the style to it this way. It's in the if else if loop

```
features[i].setStyle(style_low_risk_area);
```

This is my code.

```
     var style_low_risk_area = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: [0, 250, 0, 1]
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [220, 220, 220, 1],
            width: 1
        })
    });
    var style_mid_risk_area = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: [250, 250, 0, 1]
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [220, 220, 220, 1],
            width: 1
        })

    });
    var style_hight_risk_area = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: [250, 0, 0, 1]
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [220, 220, 220, 1],
            width: 1
        })
    });

    var style_default = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: [150, 150, 150, 1]
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [100, 100, 100, 1],
            width: 1
        })
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([102.291163, 12.809588]),
            zoom: 9
        })
    });

    var layer_source = new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'geojson/tambon_wgs84.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    });

    var layer_tambon = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: layer_source,
        style: style_default
    });

    myFuntion();
    map.addLayer(layer_tambon);

    function myFuntion(){
        var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost/Prediction_DHF2/quryDataJson.php',true);
        ourRequest.onload = function(){
            var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
            var data_tambon_code;
            var data_risk;

                layer_source.on ('change', function(evt) {
                    if (evt.target.getState() === 'ready') {
                        var features = layer_source.getFeatures();
                        var tambon_code_i;
                        var tambon_code_j;

                        for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                            tambon_code_i = features[i].get('TAMBON_COD');
                            //console.log(tambon_code_i);

                            for (var j = 0; j < ourData.length; j++) {
                                tambon_code_j = ourData[j].TAMBON_COD;
                                data_risk_j = ourData[j].L_RISK;
                                //console.log(tambon_code_j);

                                if (tambon_code_i == tambon_code_j ){
                                    // console.log(tambon_code_i);
                                    // console.log(tambon_code_j);
                                    // console.log(data_risk_j);

                                    if (data_risk_j<8.00){
                                        //console.log('low',tambon_code_i);
                                        //console.log(features[i]);
                                        features[i].setStyle(style_low_risk_area);

                                    }else if (data_risk_j<=16.00){
                                        //console.log('mid',tambon_code_i);
                                        //console.log(features[i]);
                                        features[i].setStyle(style_mid_risk_area);

                                    }else if (data_risk_j>16.01){
                                        //console.log('hight',tambon_code_i);
                                        //console.log(features[i]);
                                        features[i].setStyle(style_hight_risk_area);

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        //break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        }   
        ourRequest.send();
    }
```

Some words I ask may be typed incorrectly because I use Google Translate to help translate. If I don't understand how Please ask me again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the feature styles is probably causing more change events on the source, so you get an endless chain of change events.  When the source state is 'ready' you should turn off the event listener:

```
            var key = layer_source.on ('change', function(evt) {
                if (evt.target.getState() === 'ready') {
                    ol.Observable.unByKey(key);
                    var features = layer_source.getFeatures();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help The result did it. From your advice, Mike. Thank you very much.